# Python character encoding returns incorrect value

Tags: python, encoding

I'm using Python 2.7.11 , I get a wrong value when getting decimal value of a character from extended ascii table

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
str="è"
print(ord(str[0])) #prints 232 decimal
```

but the value of this char is 138 decimal
(http://www.asciitable.com/)

When i remove the coding utf-8 line i get this error `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe8'`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Added to the question, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

UTF-8 is not extended asci. If you check the UTF-8 table [here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/), you will see that 232 is indeed the correct ordinal.

Also, I recommend Joel on software's [UTF-8 article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

The character `è` referes in the unicode/utf-8 encoding to `0x00E8` which means `232`.

[See this reference](http://unicode-table.com/de/#00E8)

The character is contained in the extended ASCII see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21253869/python-extended-ascii-codes)
question for the extended ASCII and python.

Comment: Which encoding should I use, so the ord() will return 138?

Comment: Try `## -*- coding: latin-1 -*-`

Comment: It returns the same value. (232d)